# How can we resolve conflict between prototype and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

To resolve a conflict between jQuery and prototype,
is there any way other than asking jQuery to resolve via

> jQuery.noConflict

and using `jQuery` instead of `$('code').code`;

Can't we ask prototype `$` to step down and resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrototypeJS adds a bit more to the global JavaScript namespace than jQuery does. For example, it adds meanings for: `Ajax`, `$`, `$$`, `$F`, `Abstract`, `Form`, `$A`, `$H`, `$R`, `$w`. You can look at a complete list of classes and utilities at [api.prototypejs.org](http://api.prototypejs.org/).

So the advice you've gotten is correct, There's no simple equivalent to [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for PrototypeJS.

Answer (score 8):

You should namespace your code anyway, and jQuery gives you a good opportunity to re-claim the `$` in the same step:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function ($) {
    // $ is the jQuery object in here
    // and doesn't conflict with Prototype
});
```

As described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

I don't know if you can make Prototype "step down", but this is a perfectly elegant and working solution.

Comment: RE separate answer: Yes, you can use jQuery as the conflict resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any function in http://api.prototypejs.org/ that will give back the `$`, like `noConflict()` in jQuery.

I wonder, what feature that you need so you still using prototype? jQuery might have plugins for that feature. Using 2 libraries in same page will make your page bloated by the size of each library.